# IGN portal IE versus FireFox browser

Tags: javascript, coordinates

I have a problem with geo maps from the French IGN portal. Initializing the map is no problem. It shows up in IE browser as well the Firefox browser. So far so good.
A problem arises when a path of predefined Lon/Lat coordinates has to be plotted.
The `LonLat` coordinates have to be transformed:

```
pt.transform(OpenLayers.Projection.CRS84, getIGNmap().getMap().getProjection());
```

Thereafter the verctor can be drawn:

```
vector = new OpenLayers.Geometry.LineString(points);
```

and:

```
lineLayer.addFeatures(line);
```

Now the thing: I noticed that the FireFox browser is far more faster than the IE browser, respectively (loop of 100000 Lon/Lat, times in [ms]):

```
              FF     IE9

Transform:    542    4540

Traw:         574    2343
```

Anyone out there with some clarification?